# Devise Remember Me and Sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I'm confused with the devise gem config settings:

```
  # The time the user will be remembered without asking for credentials again.
  config.remember_for = 2.weeks

  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again.
  config.timeout_in = 10.minutes
```

I want to have a user select the "Remember Me" checkbox (i.e., keep me logged in), but the default session timeout is 10 minutes.   After 10 minutes it asks me to log in again even though I have clicked "Remember me".  If this is true then the remember_for is really meaningless.   Obviously I'm missing something here.

Comment: I dont think you should use these 2 configurations at the same time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `timeout_in` will automatically log you out within 10 minutes of inactivity and is incompatible with the `remember_me` checkbox. You can have one, but not both.

Comment: Not valid any more, take a look at pat's comment below

Comment: remember_me is not working, whether timeout is enable or disable.

Comment: In newer devise version, both modules are compatible, however rememberable seems to take precedence over timeoutable.

Answer (score 28):

Ryan is correct in that the default Devise gem does not support both the :rememberable and :timeoutable options. However, like all things Ruby, if you don't like the decision that some other coder has made, especially when it strays from the norm that most users are likely to expect, then you can simply override it.

Thanks to a (rejected) [pull request](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/pull/539) we can override this behaviour by adding the following code to the top of your Devise config file (/config/initializers/devise.rb):

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module Timeoutable
      # Checks whether the user session has expired based on configured time.
      def timedout?(last_access)
        return false if remember_exists_and_not_expired?
        last_access && last_access <= self.class.timeout_in.ago
      end

      private

      def remember_exists_and_not_expired?
        return false unless respond_to?(:remember_expired?)
        remember_created_at && !remember_expired?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This will now allow you to configure both options and have them work as you would expect.

```
config.remember_for = 2.weeks
config.timeout_in = 30.minutes
```

Comment: I'm upgrading Devise in the project I needed this patch for (I wrote the pull request mentioned) - and it turns out the commit in question is in Devise, even though the pull request was declined. So both settings should work together now.

Comment: @pat so now both features can live together? that's awesome

Comment: @alexventuraio please keep in mind my comment here was over a decade ago! I don't remember any of the context of what I was doing then, and I am pretty sure it was for a project I no longer manage now. It sounds like from other answers here the situation within Devise has changed. :)

Answer (score 12):

The information in previous answers is outdated. I've tested my project, which uses `Rails 4` and `Devise 3.5.1` and [also checked devise code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.2/lib/devise/models/timeoutable.rb#L29) to be sure.

Now it looks whether `Remember Me` checkbox was checked:

- if `yes`, it checks `if remember_exists_and_not_expired`, so basically uses `config.remember_for` for session management
- if `no`, it checks `if last_access <= timeout_in.ago`, using `config.timeout_in` correspondingly

Comment: On 16th of December 2015 the relevant checks [were removed](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/c92996646aba2d25b2c3e235fe0c4f1a84b70d24#diff-389934f38297288517a36c5adfddcc8aL29). So... sounds like "see for yourself" is the most reliable strategy now.

Comment: On Jan 2016, relevant checks add back:

### 3.5.5 - 2016-22-01

* bug fixes
 * Bring back remember_expired? implementation
 * Ensure timeouts are not triggered if remember me is being used