# Devise - remember me not working? LocalHost Issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using devise with my rails 3 app. For some reason the sign in with Remember Me is not working.

Could this be due to testing on localhost:3000 ?

in devise.rb, I have the following set:

```
config.remember_for = 2.weeks
```

In the logs, when I post a signin I see:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu May 12 20:53:04 -0700 2011
  Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"signIn"=>"LOG IN", "authenticity_token"=>"GR09TIq4uSbu6UWxDRhpfQeLWp7qtJTxkCFksLmFzdE=", "utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"on", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"xxxx@xxxxxxx-inc.com"}}
```

Is there anything wrong there?

I also have the following in my sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create ]
  include Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    clean_up_passwords(build_resource)
    render_with_scope :new
  end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "new")
    #set_flash_message :notice, :signed_in
    sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
  end

  # GET /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    #set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_in?(resource_name)
    sign_out_and_redirect(resource_name)
  end

  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.is_a?(User) && resource.banned?
      sign_out resource
      flash[:error] = "This account has been suspended."
      root_path
    else
      super
    end
  end


end
```

Any ideas why signing in and remembering is not working? Thanks

Comment: When I close the browser and go back to the localhost:3000 url I have to sign back in. Also I see the cookie has nothing set for an expiration date

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This happens because remember_me comes in params as "on", but is compared to Devise::TRUE_VALUES, which are [true, 1, '1', 't', 'T', 'true', 'TRUE'].

The easiest way is to make it work is to insure your remember_me comes as one of that values. Example of check-box(notice value="1"):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" checked="checked" />
```

Another way if you want to make it work with "on" value you can add "on" to Devise::TRUE_VALUES.
So in your config/initializers/devise.rb just add as the first line:

```
Devise::TRUE_VALUES << ["on"]
```

Comment: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/pull/5514

Answer (score 3):

The Devise *remember_user_token* cookie could be set to 'secure only', in which case it doesn't work with the development rails server on http (browser never sends it back to the server).

Check initializers/devise.rb for rememberable_options = {:secure => true}

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the sessions set aswell with *config.timeout_in = 10.minutes*?

If so see this contribution on stackoverflow which solves it [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034846/devise-remember-me-and-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

My problem with this was this single line in User.rb (I updated from Michael Hartl login mechanism to devise)

```
before_save :create_remember_token
```

I commented it out and it worked.

I also have :

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:token_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

On devise.rb, I only added `Devise::TRUE_VALUES << ["on"]` and uncommented `config.remember_for = 2.weeks`