# Devise: user has to login again each time he closes the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Devise and Omniauth for user authentication.

I want the users to stay signed in for 2 weeks after the authentication. However, whenever the user closes the browser window and reopen it, he gets the login screen again.

What is the correct configuration for the user to stay connected even after the browser was closed and re-opened?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987075/devise-remember-me-not-working-localhost-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this page on Devise's wiki:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Omniauthable,-sign-out-action-and-rememberable

Basically, Devise does not call rememberable by default when using omniauth. If you wish to do so, simple call `remember_me(@user)` on your omniauth callback and Devise will do the hardwork for you. It will also use all the configuration options set in your devise initializer.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. I had to implement the 'remember me' checkbox myself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the devise SessionsController to add cookies on log in and log out, so the controller will look like this one:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    cookies[:sign_in] = "Sign in info you want to store"
    # add this for expiration { :expires => 2.weeks.from_now }
    super
  end

  # GET /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    cookies[:sign_out] = "Sign out info you want to store"
    super
  end
end
```

Then you would have to add the following to your routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }
```

You may also set the cookie expiration time for 2 weeks.