# Remember Me option with devise rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, remember-me

I have used `devise 2.2.4`, On login page `remember_me` option is not working. It is also not throwing any error, neither it is saving anything in `remember_at` field in `user` table.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:token_authenticatable,:recoverable,      :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable#,:authentication_keys => [:login]

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :dealer_detail_id
  validates :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :presence => true
  validates_uniqueness_of :username #, :if => :email_changed?

end
```

Comment: have you added the column  

  t.datetime :remember_created_at into users table?

Comment: Check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987075/devise-remember-me-not-working-localhost-issue