# Rails Devise confirmable,rememberable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am very new to Rails, and got few questions. Will be very pleased if somebody helps me to figure out with my problems(please answer if you know even answer to one of the questions )
1) I am using Devise gem for user authentication. Now i want to activate confirmable, so user should confirm via email. Whatever i do, i keep on getting the following error - undefined method `user_confirmation_url'.  I already set config.action_mailer.default_url_options but i still get the error. FYI, reset password does work FINE!

2) Remember_Me checkbox does not take any effect. I tick the checkbox but when i close the browser and open it again it still asks me to be authenticated. I set config.remember_for = 15.minutes and did NOT set any time out, but it still asks to login.

3) Does Devise model support user roles? And is it off by default? Any link about how to use Devise User roles will be great!

Answer (score 1):

1) add :confirmable to devise in your User model (user.rb) and restart your server.  That will add the user_confirmation_url route for you.

eg. in user.rb
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :confirmable

You need to also add confirmable to your migration file as well to make it work.

2) Not sure.  Can you provide more information?  Is :timeoutable active?  Do these thread help? 
[Devise - remember me not working? LocalHost Issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987075/devise-remember-me-not-working-localhost-issue)
[Devise Remember Me and Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034846/devise-remember-me-and-sessions)

3) Devise roles: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role
Depending on what you are looking for, cancan (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or acl9 (https://github.com/be9/acl9) may be better.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

1) I already did it. Sorry for silly question - do i need to restart my computer, or just do CTRL+C to stop the server and then rails s to start it again. if so, then i already did it and no help.

2) timeout is not enabled. I saw that article you sent, but i was not able to find Devise::TRUE_VALUES anywhere in my application. so no luck so far. i just enabled remember me in config file but keep on asking to sign in each time i try to view my page.

3) Thanks will have a look.

If first 2 problems will be solved i will be so happy :)

Thanks everybody for your help

Comment: Ok, i got confirmation working, but i am still not able to get remember me working, i tick the checkbox when i sign in, but right after i close the browser and open it again it asks to sign in!! This is annoying! Anybody can help? can it be that the reason is testing on localhost:3000 , or is there anything i am missing to turn on?