# how to configure remember_me in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i m very new in web development...
please tell me whats the functionality of remember me
I am using Devise gem for user authentication
and also tell me when i checked remember me option what effect has been taken....
and how to configure remember me option using devise authentication

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034846/devise-remember-me-and-sessions

Comment: already seen but in my situation when a user select the "Remember Me" checkbox (i.e., keep me logged in)  it asks me not to log in unless untill i click log out but same thing happen when a user not select "remember me " check box then whats the use of "remember me" check box. its update database column remeber_created_at